# Cannot find 'InterfaceName' in instanceof

Tags: angular, typescript

In the same .ts file I have

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export interface Loader<T> {
    (q: string) : Observable<T[]>;
}
```

Later down in the same file, in another class I have

```
if (this.field instanceof Loader)
```

which gives the following compile error

> Cannot find name 'Loader'.

I verified that this is not a typo.

Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with interfaces. At least that's what the advanced types chapter of the handbook suggests. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `instanceof` on interfaces.
Interfaces aren't compiled to js, and `instanceof` is something that happens in runtime.

You'll need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but in your case it won't be easy because `Loader` seems to be a function...
But you can do this:

```
function isLoader(obj: any): obj is Loader {
    return obj && typeof obj === "function";
}
```

The problem is that this type guard will be true for every function you pass to it, not just a `Loader`.